# What does this mean in VS's Source Control Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I'm still trying to resolve problems created by a [user who renamed project files and the solution file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55028877/how-do-i-get-the-solution-and-project-names-back-in-sync). But now I'm trying to figure out what this means, in Visual Studio's Source Control Explorer:

> Legacy LTBI Data-Dev.sln [Legacy LTBI Data.sln]      merge,rename,edit

What I mean is, does this mean it will re-introduce the file named, "Legacy LTBI Data-Dev.sln"? Or that something, somewhere is renamed to "Legacy LTBI Data-Dev.sln"? Or that it will rename something, somewhere to "Legacy LTBI Data.sln"? I've already renamed the solution file from "Legacy LTBI Data-Dev.sln" back to what it was originally named and checked into TFS, "Legacy LTBI Data.sln".

We're using TFS 2015. I'm using VS 2017.

Comment: The meaning is there is a Rename action waiting for check-in (from "Legacy LTBI Data.sln" to "Legacy LTBI Data-Dev.sln ")

Comment: Thank you, Shayki. I don't want that rename action to go through, so how do I prevent it?

Comment: Right click on the file -> Undo Pending Changes